# How to delete record from table where field is equal to header?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

I have a sqlite table which contains duplicate headers which I would like to remove. This is my current statement.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE FIELD = "FIELD"
```

This statement, when executed, deletes the entire table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use double quotes for strings!

```
delete from table where field = 'field';
```

The SQL standard for string delimiters is single quotes.  Sometimes double quotes are used, but they are also used as escape characters for column names.  So your code was just `where field = field` and that deletes all non-NULL values.

Comment: This worked! I have to wait 10 minutes to accept the answer. Thank you!